# Database Data Difference Tool to Compare Data in Common Tables in Different Databases

Tags: database, oracle, db2

I have a source DB and a target DB and I am migrating some data from one to another. After the process I want to compare the 2 Databases against changes if any in schema as well as the **existing data**.

I know there is an tool called [Aqua Data](http://www.aquafold.com/) Studio .... but I am looking for any **FREE** tool  similar to them.

Comment: Try here: http://www.softtreetech.com/dbtools/

Comment: http://opendbiff.codeplex.com/

Comment: dbForge Data Compare for Oracle at https://www.devart.com/dbforge/oracle/datacompare/ has such functionality. There is a free Express Edition as well.

Answer (score 2):

For such synchronization I use my own tools: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576534-dump-oracle-db-schema-to-text/

It uses format that should be easy to text compare. I created similar tools for other databases I work with: Informix and PostgreSQL (also on Python recipes).

Those tools work only with schema.

Comparing data is more difficult while not all data is important (for example differences in "eventlog" table). So I created tool that dumps data according to configuration where users must write full `SELECT ... ORDER BY ...`. This tool dumps data do CSV file similar to PostgreSQL `COPY` format and because of `ORDER BY` this should be easy to text compare. Of course this has some limitation like BLOBS.

Comment: Thanks. Its a good approach. But I am looking for a free alternative to tools like dbForge or Aquadata.